# matplotlib - Scatter on the axis is only half

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, scatter

Here is my code

```
c=np.array([0,0.2,0.4,0.8,1.2,1.6,2])
A=np.array([1e-4,0.0866,0.1735,0.3085,0.4233,0.5379,0.7731])
x,y=c,A

reg=linregress(x,y)
plt.scatter(x,y)
predict=[i*reg.slope+reg.intercept for i in x]
plt.plot(x,predict,linewidth=3)

plt.xlim((min(x),max(x)))
plt.ylim((min(y),max(y)))

plt.xlabel(r'$\mathit{c} / \mathrm{ mol\cdot L^{-1}}$')
plt.ylabel(r'$A$')
plt.show()
```

And its output is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5cAs.jpg)

The left-bottom dot is only half. But I want a whole one where `xlim(left=min(x))` remains, what should I do?

Comment: your x and y limits are the problem. change : `plt.xlim((min(x),max(x)))` to `plt.xlim((min(x) - 3,max(x) + 3))`. And same for `ylim`

Comment: Thx for answering. But my teacher told me to keep `xlim(left=min(x))` while drawing the whole dot, which is like Origin-style.

Comment: `plt.scatter(..., clip_on=False)`